# Find and remove specific function calls in the string. Below is the string I have had in php variable

Tags: php

I am having the javascript code below as a string variable,
and I would need sub string of the said string which should not contain addInviewFunction, addOutviewFunction function calls.

The Remaining string should be available in another variable.

Please anyone can assist to solve this issue using PHP, would be appreciated.

```
var xyz="abcxyz";

$(document).load(function(){ console.log(HI); });

addInviewFunction({
'0': function(){ console.log(0); },
'1': function(){ console.log(1); },
'2': function(){ console.log(2); }});

addOutviewFunction({
'0': function(){ console.log('0'); },
'1': function(){ console.log('1'); },
'2': function(){ console.log('2'); }});

/*SOME JQUERY CODE HERE*/
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? Maybe add the desired output you want to have?

Comment: Why remove them, they do nothing unless you call them, and if you remove them and then call them you will get a javascritp error??? Or am I missing something

Comment: Yeah. Here I am doing nothing with the javascript, splitting the files for different platform. So I need the string other than those function calls. Hope I am clear.